# Add rel = "preload" to the core css files in magento 2

Tags: magento2, css

Is it possible to add `"rel=preload"` for all the core Magento CSS files?

I have added that for my custom CSS file.

how can this be added to all the core CSS files for Magento 2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can enable it via admin panel **Stores > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer** or via terminal.

[image: Magento 2.4 critical css]

```
bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 1
```

## How to use it

You can create a critical.css in your custom theme as the example below.

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/critical.css
```

Reference: [Magento 2.4 DevDocs - CSS critical path](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html)

Comment: Is this for core css files? i have already made the custom css file

Comment: for all css.....